# Generate some rough numbers

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes, factoring

## Background

A number `n` can be described as `B`-rough if all of the prime factors of `n` strictly exceed `B`.

## The Challenge

Given two positive integers `B` and `k`, output the first `k` `B`-rough numbers.

## Examples

Let `f(B, k)` be a function which returns the set containing the first `k` `B`-rough numbers.

```
> f(1, 10)
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

> f(2, 5)
1, 3, 5, 7, 9

> f(10, 14)
1, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the challenge? I don't understand it. Maybe explain the examples?

Comment: I don't understand why you include 1 in all your answers when it's never greater than `B`?

Comment: 1 has no prime factors, so every prime factor of 1 is larger than B and 1 should appear in the output independent of B.

Comment: @d-b Factorize `n` into primes. If all of those primes are greater than `B`, n is `B`-rough.

Comment: @AddisonCrump So for example, since the primes for 35 are 5 and 7, 35 is 4-rough? Is this some recognized common terminology? Never heard of it before. I still don't under the examples, especially not the last one. 14 numbers but what is 10??

Comment: @d-b The terminology is a joke about `B`-smoothness in number theory, which is the opposite feature. I declare `f` as `f(B, k)` in the text above, so `f(10, 14)` is the first 14 10-rough numbers.

Comment: @AddisonCrump So basically it is the first 14 primes above 10 with the exception of 1 that is always included (13 numbers above ten and 1)? If you had set k to something high in the last example a number like 121 (11x11) would have been included even though it is not a prime in itself?

Comment: @d-b I'm not sure what your confusion is. The last one is only primes, sure, because there are more primes between 11 and 121 than 10, but that doesn't imply that the sequence strictly generates primes. This just asks you to determine the first `k` numbers for which each number in the sequence only has prime factors exceeding `B`.

Comment: How is the best answer defined

Comment: @VortexYT Shortest source code, but you should compete against your only language. You're not gonna beat Jelly with Java.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>80</s>, 75 bytes

```python
lambda B,k:[i for i in range(1,-~B*k)if all(i%j for j in range(2,B+1))][:k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUcFJJ9sqOlMhLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVXDUEe3zkkrWzMzTSExJ0cjUzULrCILocJIx0nbUFMzNtoqO/Z/QVFmXolGGlCbgqGBpiYXjG@ko2CKxDU0AMqbaGr@BwA)

Thanks to *shooqie* for saving 5 bytes.

This assumes that the k'th B-rough number will never exceed \$B * k\$, which I don't know how to prove, but seems like a fairly safe assumption (and I can't find any counterexamples).

Alternate solution:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
B,k=input()
i=1
while k:
 if all(i%j for j in range(2,B+1)):print i;k-=1
 i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxCsMgFAXQ3a@4S0CJhb7QKcXFP8mQNDfKi4gh9Ottz37Kt@2nTr1HnwK1XM06wyDm3plXpNmAG5acLYcD21lxgIq66Ge1k4@jODeXSm3gOz3@ERyD9C5PL68f)

This solution does *not* make the above solution. And is much more efficient.

Comment: Hmm, that assumption is probably verifiable, but an interesting problem nonetheless. I'll bounty for a proof.

Comment: Why not `lambda B,k:[i for i in range(1,-~B*k)if all(i%j for j in range(2,B+1))][:k]` ?

Comment: @BlackOwlKai That sounds cool. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2983364/bounds-on-the-size-of-rough-numbers

Comment: @Anush Sadly, my proof didn't work, because I made a mistake

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>53</s> 44 bytes

```hs
b%k=take k[n|n<-[1..],all((>0).mod n)[2..b]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcVBCoAgEADAr@xFULBFPVc/6AXiYSMhUbcoj/3dosvMTneOpfS@ijw1yhGy54fHwVvEoKkUKWejsB4bsPIOcQ2hV0oME1Q6FzivxA28FdZocL/WfIX@Ag)

*Thanks to [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz) for -9 bytes!*

```hs
b%k=                       -- given inputs b and k
 take k                    -- take the first k elements from 
  [n|n<-[1..]              -- the infinite list of all n > 0
   ,all            [2..b]] -- where all numbers from 2 to b (inclusive)
      ((>0).mod n)         -- do not divide n.
```

Comment: This can be [simplified](https://tio.run/##HcVBCoAgEADAr@xFULBFPVc/6AXiYSMhUbcoj/3dosvMTneOpfS@ijw1yhGy54fHwVvEoKkUKWejsB4bsPIOcQ2hV0oME1Q6FzivxA28FdZocL/WfIX@Ag) somewhat

Comment: @H.PWiz Right, somehow I only thought about taking the `(>b)`-part inside the comprehension (which does not work) but not the other way around. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>35</s> 32 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to nwellnof!*

```perl6
{grep(*%all(2..$^b),1..*)[^$^k]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzq9KLVAQ0s1MSdHw0hPTyUuSVPHUE9PSzM6TiUuO7b2f3FipUKahqGOoYGmNReEY6RjCmcbGugYmkB5pqoaxjVGmv8B)

An anonymous code block that takes two integers and returns a list of integers.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                              }  # Anonymous code block
 grep(             ,1..*)        # Filter from the positive integers
      *              # Is the number
       %             # Not divisible by
        all(      )  # All of the numbers
            2..$^b   # From 2 to b
                         [^$^k]   # And take the first k numbers
```

Comment: What does `all` do?

Comment: @AddisonCrump `all` checks if all the elements in the list are truthy. I will be adding an explanation for the whole thing shortly

Comment: @nwellnhof Wow! So that's what Junctions are useful for!

Comment: Yes, note that you could also use `[&]` instead of `all`.

Comment: @AddisonCrump I guess `all` isn't being used in that way any more, so I should update my answer. `all` creates a Junction of the values in the range `2..b`, and any operations performed on the Junction gets performed on all the values simulataneously. When it is evaluated in Boolean context by the `grep`, this collapses into whether all the values in the Junction are truthy, ie non-zero

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
1Æf>Ạɗ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/wcFua3cNdC05OV/4P5Bn8NzQBAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
↑foΛ>⁰pN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxLT8c7PtHjVuKPD7//@/8X9DAwA)

Takes \$B\$ as first and \$ k \$ as second input.

```
↑         -- take the first k elements 
       N  -- from the natural numbers
 f        -- filtered by
  o   p   -- the prime factors
   Λ>⁰    -- are all larger than the first input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
1µg³!¤Ịµ⁴#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w0Nb0Q5sVDy15uLvr0NZHjVuU/wMFDf4bmgAA)

#### How it works

```
1µg³!¤Ịµ⁴#    Dyadic main link. Left = B, right = k
       µ⁴#    Take first k numbers satisfying...
  g             GCD with
   ³!¤          B factorial
      Ị         is insignificant (abs(x) <= 1)?
1µ            ... starting from 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 68 bytes

Takes input as `(b)(k)`.

```javascript
b=>k=>(o=[],n=1,g=d=>(d<2?o.push(n)==k:n%d&&g(d-1))||g(b,n++))(b)&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcpBDoIwEEbhvfewmT8UYolujIMHMS4ohaqQGWLVFXevbI3L9@U92k@buud9fpWioc8DZ8/NyA0pX65W2NnIYc1wqs9aze90IwHzeJRtMCZSKB2wLJG8laIAyMMYzZ1K0qmvJo00kAO5HbD51Rp0@MP1I7cH8hc)

#### Commented

```javascript
b => k => (             // input = b and k
  o = [],               // o[] = output array
  n = 1,                // n = value to test
  g = d => (            // g = recursive function, taking the divisor d
    d < 2 ?             // if d = 1:
      o.push(n) == k    //   push n into o[] and test whether o[] contains k elements
    :                   // else:
      n % d && g(d - 1) //   if d is not a divisor of n, do a recursive call with d - 1
    ) ||                // if the final result of g() is falsy,
    g(b, n++)           // do a recursive call with d = b and n + 1
)(b)                    // initial call to g() with d = b
&& o                    // return o[]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
ＮθＮη≔⁰ζＷ‹Ｌυη«≦⊕ζ¿¬Φθ∧κ¬﹪ζ⊕κ⊞υζ»Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCoMwEEXX5iuynEAKCt25kkJBqOIvpJqaYExsHi1Y@u1pxC6cxcC5zJ3TC2Z7w1SMtV6Cb8N85xaepERHFokr5@SoIad4TfQWUnEMN@5cWnr0AgKhWBCCPyhr2PI/r3Vv@cy158NezOQDQ2s8XKXym4riSg8wUbyFjRmCMrBSfCjCRPZBWdYFl0z7qy/qrNQeLsz5ZCdljEWOinM8vdQP) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `B` and `k`.

```
≔⁰ζ
```

Set `z` to 0.

```
Ｗ‹Ｌυη«
```

Repeat until we have `k` values.

```
≦⊕ζ
```

Increment `z`.

```
¿¬Φθ∧κ¬﹪ζ⊕κ
```

Divide `z` by all the numbers from `2` to `B` and see if any remainder is zero.

```
⊞υζ»
```

If not then push `z` to the predefined empty list.

```
Ｉυ
```

Cast the list to string and implicitly output it.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 68 bytes

```javascript
b=>g=(k,i=1,j=b)=>k?j>1?i%j?g(k,i,j-1):g(k,i+1):[i,...g(k-1,i+1)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcpBCoMwEIXhfe8hzGASHLEbYZKDiAu1GjKKKbX0@jF1V7r738eT4TMc0ys833qPjzktnEa2nmFVgUkJj8h2dWLJhUKc/7oSTdheWebogjLG5Knpgr7t@jTF/YjbbLboYQFCoArx9qs1wv0P8w@oQUwn)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 52 chars, 104 bytes

```
r←a f w;i
r←,i←1⋄→3
i+←1⋄→3×⍳∨/a≥πi⋄r←r,i
→2×⍳w>↑⍴r
```

Above it seems the rows after 'r←a f w;i' have names 1 2 3;test:

```
  o←⎕fmt
  o 1 h 2
┌2───┐
│ 1 2│
└~───┘
  o 1 h 1
┌1─┐
│ 1│
└~─┘
  o 10 h 14
┌14───────────────────────────────────────┐
│ 1 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59│
└~────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞ʒÒ¹›P}²£
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9vc2FiaWX//@KInsqSw5LCueKAulB9wrLCo///MTAKMTQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@koGunoGRfmRAa9v9Rx7xTkw5PinzUsCugNuLQ4v86/6OjDXUMDWJ1oo10TIGkoYGOoUlsLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞          # Infinite list starting at 1: [1,...]
 ʒ    }    # Filter it by:
  Ò        #  Get all prime factors of the current number
   ¹›      #  Check for each if they are larger than the first input
     P     #  And check if it's truthy for all of them
       ²£  # Leave only the leading amount of items equal to the second input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 56 bytes

```ruby
->b,k{(1..).lazy.reject{|n|
(2..b).any?{n%_1<1}}.take k}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3LXTtknSyqzUM9fQ09XISqyr1ilKzUpNLqmvyarg0jPT0kjT1EvMq7avzVOMNbQxra_VKErNTFbJrIfrXFyi4RRsa6BiaxOqV5McnQkQXLIDQAA)